# context - url wirh parameter

Tags: 6

I'm using Drupal 6 and [context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context). It seems that context does not react on path like this **mypath?123** Is there any way to check such path with context?

Comment: Just to clarify, you're wanting to trigger a context reaction when you a query parameter in the URL (e.g. *mypath?my_val=123* )?

Comment: yes. I solved it by installing context_php module and added condition: "$curr_uri = check_plain(request_uri());

if($curr_uri == '/mypath?ak'){
   return TRUE;
}". If you know better solution, please let me now.

Comment: There's a dedicated module that does what you're wanting. I'd say it's *slightly better*, insofar that it doesn't rely on your own custom PHP.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting a module-based solution the [Context Query Parameters module](https://www.drupal.org/project/context_query_param) adds *Query String* condition that lets you check for multiple query values.

> This module introduces a Context condition that allows you to trigger
>   a Context based on query parameters on a given page request.

Comment: I came across that module but it is for D7 only.

Comment: Ah, in that case, you should post your own found solution as answer for future readers still on D6.